# Property created through generic inheritance doesn't exist

Tags: c#, generics, abstract-class, code-first

In my project I keep several class libraries for implementation of common functions. One of them has a class LoganBaseObject

This class adds common columns to tables I design with code-first (primary key column, when and by whom the data was created/edited, etc).

I implement this class through inheritance on the classes that represent the tables in my database, however, I'm very confused as it works fine on one of these classes, but not at all on another (or so it appears). See below:

Here's LoganBaseObject

```
namespace Logan.Base
{
    public abstract class LoganBaseObject<T>
        where T : LoganBaseObject<T>
    {
        [Key]
        public Int64 PKey { get; set; }

        public LoganBaseObject()
        {
            PKey = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Below are the classes where I've implemented this. The implementation for Role works fine, but the User class doesn't get a PKey property...

```
namespace Logan.Web.Objects
{
    public class Role : LoganBaseObject<Role>
    {
        public string RoleName { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }

        public Role()
        {
            RoleName = String.Empty;
            Users = new List<User>();
        }
    }

    public class User : LoganBaseObject<User>
    {
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public string Biography { get; set; }
        public virtual Role Role { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Article> Articles { get; set; }

        public User()
        {
            Username = String.Empty;
            EmailAddress = String.Empty;
            Password = String.Empty;
            Biography = String.Empty;
            Articles = new List<Article>();
        }
    }
}
```

I don't see any difference in either class inside Logan.Web.Objects so I can't understand why the PKey property exists on Roles but not on Users.

I'd really appreciate it if anyone could have a look here and help me to resolve this. I can't move forward developing the system if this isn't resolved.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why don't you try to define your PK mappings expilictly?

Comment: A friend helped me set this up, and when I don't inherit the LoganBaseObject class, then lambda expressions break in the DBContext classes (where I set up `Property(p => p.Username).IsRequired();` and such. So I'm not sure how to get around that else I'd just define RoleId and UserId columns in the Logan.Web.Objects classes

Comment: Why is the base class generic? You are not using the type anywhere in the code. Is there some more code that uses that, which is not included here? In that case it might be that code that makes the difference...

Answer (score 0):

Your generic class doesn't use any type parameter so you can make it non-generic. And "Pkey" isn't a convention for EF for primary keys. You should rename it as "Id" or you have to explicitly define it as a primary key in your mappings like :

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Role>().HasKey(t => t.PKey);
modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasKey(t => t.PKey);
```

Comment: Now I look more closely, this actually isn't the problem... The problem is that none of the properties for User or Role are exposed to the models in my MVC app. I'm not sure how to expose them though as I don't want these classes to be visible to MVC

Comment: I'll ask a new question for it. Yes I'm using scaffolding